# can i use a pre-configured machine image w/Ruby/Java pre-installed on machines with diff.RAM+CPU

Tags: java, ruby, amazon-ec2, cloud, rackspace-cloud

I have created a machine image which has some languages/frameworks installed in it-- eg Java, Ruby etc.

The idea being, I can quickly initialise a new virtual machine (for eg on Amazon EC2 or Rackspace Cloud) with this machine image, and then run some code on that virtual machine.

What I am not sure about is, suppose I created my machine image in a server with 1GB RAM /2 Ghz CPU-- will I be able to use this image as it is in a virtual machine with a different CPU+RAM config? Eg will I be able to use my image directly in a virtual machine with 8GM RAM?

Or is there any manual config/adjustment I have to make, to ensure that my machine image works on the virtual machine with a diff. CPU+RAM config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surely do the Image mapping to higher/lower configuration of CPU and RAM. However you cannot change the bit architecture of image. For example 32 bit image can not be configured for 64 bit machine and 64 bit images can not be configured for 32 bit machines too.
You dont have to do any configuration to make it work at least in amazon ec2.

Comment: I am sure you meant 32bit vs 64bit, right!??

Comment: Ohhh...I am sorry. You are right. I meant 32 and 64 bit machine..:)

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this on Amazon EC2; you create an [Amazon Machine Image](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) (AMI) which is a complete definition of your virtual machine with all its configuration, and then you can start a new instance of it using different [instance types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-types.html#AvailableInstanceTypes) with varying CPU / RAM configurations.

I'm not familiar with Rackspace Cloud, but I'd be surprised if they didn't offer something similar.